# Pandas to_excel formatting float values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I'm exporting a dataframe to an excel file using [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) from pandas but I need that all the number values (float64) to be formatted (without specifing each columns because that will be variable) as a string (BRL currency) when exported.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numero': {0: '044121', 1: '044121'}, 'Serie': {0: '0', 1: '0'}, 'Finalidade': {0: '1', 1: '1'}, 
                  'CNPJ_CPF_Emit': {0: '01039778000177', 1: '01039778000177'}, 
                  'Rz_Emit': {0: 'VINHEDOS INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO DE PAPEIS LTDA.', 1: 'VINHEDOS INDUSTRIA E COMERCIO DE PAPEIS LTDA.'}, 
                  'PIS_Valor': {0: 1620.98, 1: 1210.42}, 'COFINS_Valor': {0: 7466.32, 1: 5575.28}, 'Valor_IPI': {0: 3628.22, 1: 2709.28}, 
                  'Valor_ICMS': {0: 13396.5, 1: 10003.5}, 
                  'Valor_Total_Nota': {0: 201337.5, 1: 201337.5}, 'Valor_Frete': {0: '', 1: ''}})

df.to_excel(my_path, index=False, freeze_panes=(1,0))
```

resulting in:

[image]

and the desired excel output would be:

[image]

Is it possible? If so, how is the better way to do it?

Can be done using the float_format parameter when writing the excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to customize the format if you install `xlsxwriter` (with another code, it can work with `openpyxl` too).

```
# pip install xlsxwriter
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:

    # write the dataframe before modify the sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    wb = writer.book  # get workbook
    ws = writer.sheets['Sheet1']  # and worksheet

    # add a new format then apply it on right columns
    currency_fmt = wb.add_format({'num_format': 'R$ #,###.##'})
    ws.set_column('F:J', None, currency_fmt)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before saving

```
def format_currency(value):
    if pd.isna(value):
        return ''
    return 'R$ {:.2f}'.format(value)
    #For saving in Brl
for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns:
df[col] = df[col].apply(format_currency)
```

This should do the trick. You need just place in between the df declaration and saving it

Answer (score 0):

I've used both answers and came up with this to solve my problem:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(my_path, engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
  df.to_excel(writer, index=False, freeze_panes=(1,0), sheet_name="export")
  wb = writer.book
  ws = writer.sheets["export"]
  formato_moeda = wb.add_format({'num_format': 'R$ #.###,##'})
  for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).columns:
    col = df.columns.get_loc(col)
    ws.set_column(col, col, None, formato_moeda)
```

[image]

Thanks Corralien and Arunbh Yashaswi for the help!

Comment: Use `with`, don't use manual close calls.  https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement

Comment: ok, I'll change and edit it here. Would you care to explain why is it better using with?

Comment: Read the link; it's cleaner, more maintainable, more robust, helps prevent mistakes and memory leaks, etc, etc, etc

Comment: Didn't saw the link. Thank you!